# Keep "Always use this app to open [filetype] files" unchecked by default

Tags: windows-10

The "Always use this app to open [filetype] files" textbox has been the bane of my existence in Windows 10 for years now.  I virtually *never* want to actually change the program to open the file with, so I have to constantly keep vigilant and *always* uncheck the box, lest I have to go through and manually change the default program for the thousandth time.  I'm sick of it.  How do I make that accursed option default to unchecked?

Comment: This issue appears to work better in Windows 11 which I started using some time back. Open with provides "Always" or "Just once" so nothing changes. My Windows 10 Open With has the check box vacant, so again no changes. I not sure what might have happened to your machine.

Comment: You can remove the option from the dialog.  If I get some time I'll write up the solution but it is here under **Step 3:** [Remove_Always_use_this_app_to_open](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/156072-how-add-remove-open-always-use-app-windows-10-a.html#3)